# How do I keep my footer text from appearing outside my footer

Tags: html, css

I have another problem. The text in my footer keeps appearing outside my footer underneath. How do I get it to stay inside the footer div?Here is the html code for the footer:

```
<div id="footer">

<!-- If you'd like to support WordPress, having the "powered by" link somewhere on your blog is the best way; it's our only promotion or advertising. -->
<p>Contact | Privacy Policy | Call 1300 IT 4 U (483 678)</p>
<br />
<br />
<br />
 <p><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> Pty Ltd 2000-2014 is proudly powered by<a href="http://wordpress.org/">WordPress</a> and designed by <a href="http://www.wpart.org/">WPart.</a> All Rights Reserved. Stathis Arcade 262 Maquarie Street Suite 2-3 | Liverpool NSW 2170
<?php wp_footer(); ?></p>
</div>
```

Here is the footer css:

```
#footer {

    width: 960px;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    padding-top: 10px;

    padding-right:10px;

    height: 50px;

    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;

    font-size: 12px;

    font-weight: normal;

    color: #002899;

    padding-left: 10px;

    text-align: center;

    position:absolute;

    overflow: hidden;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/b28vz/

Comment: If you could strip the php - and maybe make a fiddle with the important code, you'll get more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your height is fixed, in this case `50px`, and if the content size is more than that, it will overflow. Instead of `50px`, try `height:auto;`(which I believe is default, so if you remove the `height:50px;` that would be enough).

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all the `<br>`s pushing the text down.  You're setting a height of `50px` and making it much larger than that.  I removed the `<br>` tags and reduced the top padding on the footer and it looked mostly fine, but there really should be no reason to set your footer to a specific height. If you wanted those `<br>`s, then remove or alter the `height:50px` on your footer class.

http://jsfiddle.net/29jA3/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have a set height on an element that has content that does not fit inside of it.  I could suggest a myriad of things, but I think that most of my larger solutions - will mess up other things in your theme... try taking the height and overflow hidden rules out of your CSS. Let the content decide the size of it's parent.